# Example of a PDF that is not differentiable

Tags: probability-theory, derivatives, probability-distributions, density-function

Suppose my continuous probability distribution has a PDF. I'm wondering if the PDF is differentiable on the real line. The definition does not require that a pdf be differentiable, but I don't recall seeing examples of pdfs that aren't differentiable. Can the pdf be non-differentiable?

Comment: There exists random variables that don't have pdf's (if you consider that not being differentiable).  They are generically called "Singular Distributions".

Comment: Thank you Mark, but I'm assuming the pdf exists.

Comment: Yes the PDF can be non differentiable, actually the PDF can be any measurable, nonnegative, integrating to 1, function, so pick up your favorite measurable, nonnegative, integrating to 1, non differentiable function and you are done.

Comment: @Did Sometimes we also want continuity from a PDF. Because $F'(x)=f(x)$ only really makes sense if $f$ is continuous. However thankfully this is not so hard.

Comment: @ZacharySelk Sorry but continuity is a very *unreasonable* assumption to impose on a PDF (and I think that the fact that you took care to taylor a continuous example in your answer is simply misleading).

Comment: Thank you! Follow up in case it is differentiable: <http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2017796/do-all-cdfs-eventually-become-horizontal>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just find any non differentiable, continuous, nonnegative function which integrates to $1$. For example $f(x)=x 1_{(0,1)}(x)+(2-x)1_{(1,2)}$.

Answer (score 5):

Another very classical non-differentiable pdf is the Laplace distribution (or double exponential) defined by $$f(x)=\dfrac{1}{2}e^{-|x|}$$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution). This non-differentiability being limited to $x=0$.

Laplace distribution occurs for example in a natural way as the pdf or $X_1-X_2$ where $X_1,X_2$ are independant identically distributed exponential random variables (with pdf $e^{-x}\mathbb{1}_{[0,\infty)}$).