# Do all CDFs eventually become Horizontal?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, derivatives, probability-distributions, density-function

> If a pdf $f$ is differentiable, does it have to satisfy $\lim _{x\to \infty}f'(x)\to0$?

At first I thought this was obvuously true, but I think it can be false if the CDF has infinitely many inflection points (if that's even possible - see picture).

That is, just because the integral (CDF) tends to $1$ doesn't mean that it eventually coincides with the horizoal line $y=1$.

[image]

Comment: The idea is a bit like this: you can make an arbitrarly tall triangle have an arbitrarly small area, if you give it a sufficiently thin basis. This can be approximated with $C^\infty$ functions that are $0$ outside of the basis. By Lagrange's theorem, the slope of this triangle-approximating function will be, at some point, $\approx 2\dfrac{\text{height}}{\text{basis}}\gg 1$.

Comment: This is exactly what I have proposed.

Comment: @JeanMarie Didn't see that.

Comment: No problem ! I posted it 3 minutes ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the title: it's possible for a CDF to be strictly monotone over the whole line, for example the CDF of a normal distribution has this property.

Regarding the question in the body: it's also possible for a pdf to fail to go to zero, and for its derivative to fail to go to zero. The classic example of this is something like $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n} g(x-n)$ where $g(x)=\begin{cases} 0 & x<0 \\ 4x & 0 \leq x \leq 1/2 \\ 4-4x & 1/2< x \leq 1 \\ 0 & x>1 \end{cases}$.

(The graph of $g$ is just a triangle with area $1$.) This example is not differentiable everywhere, but it can be smoothed as needed while still keeping it a pdf. For instance a $C^1$ version is $g(x)=\begin{cases} 0 & x<0 \\ \frac{1}{C} x^2(x-1)^2 & 0 \leq x \leq 1 \\ 0 & x>1 \end{cases}$ where $C=\int_0^1 x^2(x-1)^2 dx$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $T$ be the "tent function" defined by

$$T_n(x)=max(0,n-n^4*|x|)$$

Its support is $[-\dfrac{1}{n^3},\dfrac{1}{n^3}]$.

As its maximum is at height $n$, the area under this curve is clearly $\dfrac{1}{n^2}$

If we define $f$ by $f(x)=\dfrac{6}{\pi^2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}T_n(x-n)$ we have a pdf with arbitrary large slopes as $n \rightarrow \infty.$

Comment: Great minds think alike I suppose :)

Comment: By $*$ do you mean usual multiplication?

Comment: Yes, I feared to be misunderstood if a place no operation sign.

Comment: For the sake of nit-picking, this is not differentiable. Though the differentiable case is not too different: just more tedious notation.

Comment: @Ian I appreciate your humor

Comment: @JeanMarie No joke really, at about the same time we came up with essentially the same example, just scaled a little bit differently.

Comment: G. Sassatelli You are right, one needs to convolve it with a differentiable function, itself a pdf in order to get a pdf, but one has to take care that this operation doesn't erase too much the peaks...

Comment: @JeanMarie My polynomial interpolant idea dodges that problem.

Comment: @Ian I fully agree !